# Favicon not displaying in most browsers and shows odd src path. React + Express Server

Tags: reactjs, express

I am serving a react application on an express server deployed to Heroku. Locally I can easily see my favicon. When deployed it is not showing up.  I am getting a status 200 on the file but when I click preview it is showing this as the src:https://reactportfoliodh.herokuapp.com//favicon.ico.  For the life of me I cannot figure out why it is showing two forward slashes.  To make matters worse another person says they CAN see it. I have already tried emptying my cache and tried multiple computers...Anyone?

Comment: How do you reference the favicon in your code? Are you using serve-favicon? https://github.com/expressjs/serve-favicon. You'll need to provide more information if the community is going to help you.

Comment: In the network tab, I am getting a status 200 on the .ico file but here is what I get when I look at preview:

<html>
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="https://reactportfoliodh.herokuapp.com//favicon.ico" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>
Double forward slash the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help you, but here's how I handled adding the favicon to my React/Express app...

First of all, install the `serve-favicon` and `path` NPM modules
`$ npm install --save serve-favicon && npm install --save path`

In your main Express server file (`index.js`, in my case), add the following:

```
const express = require("express"),
    path = require("path"),
    app = express(),
    favicon = require("serve-favicon")

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, "public", "images", "favicons", "favicon.ico")))
```

The `app.use()` line should point to the directory where your icon is located - in my case, it is in `public/images/favicons/favicon.ico`.

And that's it - no need to include it in your `index.html` - it should be available throughout your app.

Comment: So this is spot on and I had tried this, but didnt work. Ends up I was forwarding with masking from godaddy and as soon as I turned off masking it worked fine, something with the masking